# How to show notification in notification area in Cordova?

Tags: cordova, localnotification

How to send notification in notification area using Cordova without push-notification service like:

```
window.plugins.PluginName.Notify('Title','');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cordova [local notifications plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications). Inside the [documentation](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki) you can find everything you need to know; anyway this is an example code:

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: 1,
    text: "Single Notification",
    sound: isAndroid ? 'file://sound.mp3' : 'file://beep.caf',
    data: { secret:key }
});
```

Comment: I am trying https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn757051.aspx but I am not able to install it. Can you tell how can I use it ?

Comment: Have you tried with the "custom git repository" install?

Comment: Yes downloaded it as zip and add file manually to copy past but it did not work. Can you please screen shot how should I do it ?

Comment: We're going off topic here; if you want, ask another question about installing a custom plugin in visual studio. Anyway, if you've found this answer useful accept it.